# How can I make Json.Net ignore duplicated items in lists when deserializing?

Tags: c#, json.net

Let's say that I have the following JSON object:

```js
{
    "numbers": {
        1,
        2,
        3,
        3,
    }
}
```

```cs
public class Test
{
    [JsonProperty("numbers")]
    public List<int> Numbers { get; set;}
}
```

How can I make it ignore duplicated values in the list? So it ends up being something like `1, 2, 3` instead of `1, 2, 3, 3`.

Comment: If you like writing code, then write a converter for your serializer. If you just want to solve the problem, then just use Distinct after the fact

Comment: This isn't a job for the deserialization layer, any more than (say) multiplying every number by 2 would be. If you have much more logic like this and you need a separation for the serialization classes and the "real" data, you can use something like Automapper to bridge the gap.

Comment: As mentioned above, this isn't really the job of the serializer.  So you need to do this yourself.  You could eliminate duplicates e.g. 1) in an [`[OnDeserialized]`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationCallbacks.htm) callback.  2) In a [custom converter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm) 3) By replacing the `List<T>` with a `HashSet<T>`.